# How to list the maximum value of a column in between rows with a value duplicated?

Tags: sql, derby

I have a table with 3 columns. I want make a SQL query that results in the maximum value in between the occurrences of DP_ID = A

| ID | DP_ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 2 | B | 264 |
| 3 | B | 265 |
| 4 | B | 266 |
| 5 | A | 10 |
| 6 | B | 115 |
| 7 | B | 116 |
| 8 | A | 25 |

The desired output would be:

| ID | DP_ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | B | 266 |
| 7 | B | 116 |

I've tried to make a subquery to filter the table based on the ID of the rows that have DP_ID=A. The problem is that I can only retrieve one instance bye time. My desired output would list all the occurrences of it

Comment: as Derby doesn't support LAG or window function even after so man ears, ou should think about making that quer in  th application

Comment: Derby doesn't even seem to support the `WITH` clause. So while we *could* build groups with counting A rows with an ID less or equal to a B row's ID in a subquery, we would have to do this twice and end up with a query that is hard to read and probably even slow. So, I agree with nbk, with such a DBMS it is easier to do this with a simple loop in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Derby is a quite limited database that does not support window functions or CTEs.

**Note**: I would strongly suggest you switch to H2 that has a similar footprint and offers much better capabilities.

The query becomes tediously long and non-performant in Derby, but can be written as:

```
select *
from (
  select
    t.*, 
    (select sum(case when dp_id = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) from t x
     where x.id <= t.id) as g
  from t
) z
where dp_id <> 'A'
  and value = (
  select max(value) as mv
  from (
    select
      t.*, 
      (select sum(case when dp_id = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) from t x 
       where x.id <= t.id) as g
    from t
  ) y
  where dp_id <> 'a' and y.g = z.g
  )
```

Result:

```
ID  DP_ID  VALUE  G
--  -----  -----  -
 4  B        266  1
 7  B        116  2
```

The data script that demonstrates this example is:

```
create table t(
   id    integer  not null
  ,dp_id varchar(2) not null
  ,value integer  not null
);

insert into t(id,dp_id,value) values (1,'A',10);
insert into t(id,dp_id,value) values (2,'B',264);
insert into t(id,dp_id,value) values (3,'B',265);
insert into t(id,dp_id,value) values (4,'B',266);
insert into t(id,dp_id,value) values (5,'A',10);
insert into t(id,dp_id,value) values (6,'B',115);
insert into t(id,dp_id,value) values (7,'B',116);
insert into t(id,dp_id,value) values (8,'A',25);
```